# Floating division does not work on python for 1.2/0.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a pretty easy question.

I am doing a division of 1.2/0.2 on python 3.7.0 and I get 5.9999999999 instead of a clear 6. It is obvious that 1.2/0.2 is 6 so I don't understand why I am getting this result.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to avoid such problems use [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) built-in module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can round a number, for example

```
round(1.2 / 0.2)
```

would give an answer of 6. The reason your getting this is due to floating point precision error.

> It's a problem caused when the internal representation of floating-point numbers, which uses a fixed number of binary digits to represent a decimal number. It is difficult to represent some decimal number in binary, so in many cases, it leads to small roundoff errors.

you can read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floating-point-error-in-python/)

Comment: cool, works for the moment. Anyway, it is very weird that python behave this way.

Comment: Not really, most programming languages: Python, JavaScript, or C++ and many more, all have rounding errors when displaying floats. A float is actually stored as 3 integers, you have your exponent which is the whole number part of the float, for example `4.665` 4 would be the exponent, then you have the significand which is the decimal part `.665`. finally you have the sign `+` or `-`.

Comment: the rounding error is caused as a result of the way in which floats are stored in a computer.

Comment: thanks for the clarification Jared, very richen.